# Loading a Keras model given an already opened file

Tags: python, file, tensorflow, keras

The common way to load a saved model is with `keras.models.load_model` method.

```
keras.models.load_model("/mypath/model.h5")
```

My question is if this can be done giving a file object, something like this:

```
file = open("/mypath/model.h5")
keras.models.load_model(file)
```

This code doesn't work, I've searched on internet for this but there has been no luck.

Comment: What's wrong with using `load_model()` or `load_weights()`?

Comment: @NawraC I need to launch it into cloud functions, so h5 file must be loaded from cloud first and then  passed to some sort of load model function. Saving just weights as json gives me ValueError: The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.

Comment: I guess you have to look into Keras' code where `load_model()` is, and see how they are opening and reading the file. I don't know of any way to load a model other than using these two functions so if you want to create your own, you can start by seeing how they do it. Good luck.

Comment: A file issue with some framework is not an `artificial-intelligence` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Could you share the complete Traceback to know the root cause of this issue. Thanks!